# "Emulate" minimum OpenGL specs?

Tags: opengl, standards, emulation

We're working with OpenGL 4.3. However, we're afraid that we're using features that are working with our graphics card, but not in the "minimal" required specs for OpenGL 4.3.

**Is there any possibility to emulate the minimum behaviour?** For example, to make the graphics card reject any non-standard texture formats etc.? (Could also be in software, speed doesn't matter for testing compatibility...)

**Update**

In the best case, a minimum set in all aspects would be perfect, so it is guaranteed the application works on all graphics cards supporting OpenGL 4.3. So this emulation mode should:

- Reject all features/extensions deprecated in 4.3
- Reject all features/extensions newer than 4.3
- Only support required formats, no optional formats (for example for textures and renderbuffers)
- Only support the minimum required precision for calculations
- Have the minimum value of the supported Limits than can be queried via GetInteger (for example a MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS of 16)

Comment: I can't write a full answer nor can I confirm my statement right now. But while creating your context you need to set the context to core profile, define the version you want to use and disable forward compatibility. This should limit your function exactly to the specified version. How to do this depends on how you create your context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [reference GLSL compiler](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/) that will solve half of this problem. But, as for the rest ... AMD, NV and Intel all have their own compliance issues and policies regarding how loosely they believe in following the specification.

I have seen each one of these vendors implicitly enable extensions from versions of OpenGL they should not have (without so much as a warning in the compiler log), and that is just the GLSL side of things. It is likely that Mesa can serve the role of greatest common factor for feature testing, but for OpenGL versions much older than 4.3. Mesa is effectively a minimalist implementation, and usually a few years behind the big hardware vendors.

Ideally GL's [debug output](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Debug_Output) extension, which is conveniently a core feature in GL 4.3, would issue API warnings if you use a feature your requested context version does not support. However, each vendor has different levels of support for this; AMD is generally the best. NVIDIA may even require you to enable ["OpenGL Expert" mode](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/coresdk/nvapi/group__oglapi.html) before it spits out any genuinely useful information.

---

If all else fails, there is an [XML file](https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/doc/registry/public/api/gl.xml) published by Khronos that you can parse to figure out which version and/or extension ANY OpenGL constant, function or enumerant is provided by. I wrote a simple project to do this with half a day's effort: https://github.com/Andon13/glvs. You could write some sort of validator yourself based on that principle.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of [OpenGL Loading Libraries](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) that will do what you need to some degree. GLEW just gives you everything and lets you pick and choose what you want. But there are others which generate more specific loaders.

[GL3w](https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w) for example generates only the core OpenGL functions, ignoring extensions entirely.

For a more comprehensive solution, there are [glLoadGen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home) or [GLad](https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad). Both of these are generators for the headers and loading code. But both of them allow you to specify exactly which version of OpenGL you want and exactly which extensions you want. GLad even has a [web application](http://glad.dav1d.de/) that can generate headers and download them to your computer.

In the interests of full disclosure, I wrote glLoadGen.